# Need to have all product names in the hyphenated format "some-product-name" but also display it properly without the added hyphens

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Is this possible to do by using only the one name column in the database ?

Say I have the following value in the name field of my products table:

```
Samsung Blu-Ray Writer
```

When the html renders in the view I am going to parse the string and replace all the spaces with
hyphens and remove all capitals, so it will look like so: samsung-blu-ray-writer

When this product link is clicked it will send to the server a request to get
the product by the name of samsung-blu-ray-writer. Of course in the database
the product name is Samsung Blu-Ray writer. So when I create the query I will of course
need to replace all the hyphens with spaces again but this will also remove the required "-" in Blu-Ray.

I understand I can just use two fields, say ProductName and DisplayName. But this seems like
a waste and hopefully there's an easy solution to this.

Even if initially save all product names as hyphenated then I would still loose the
hyphens that were meant to be in the actual product name when I parse the string to replace them with spaces for display purposes.

Comment: having tow fields to store display name and product name is not waste at all if that is the requirement.

Comment: Just hoping there's some easy logic that I could use to turn the display name into hyphenated one and back without loosing the hyphens that are meant to be in the actual product name.

Comment: Why do you need to change it back? SEO and other prettifying formatting of strings should be one direction only. The prettified string should not then turn around and be used to identify the product in the database again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace the hyphens with spaces on the second trip. Look at how Stack Overflow does it. Put the ID in the URL before the product name, then look up the product by ID on the return trip. By doing it this way, it doesn't matter how you formatted the product name in the URL - it's just for display purposes.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do it as such and the search would be faster too. Was just going for ultra clean url's like here for example: http://www.harveynorman.com.au/nikon-coolpix-s2600-digital-camera-purple.html

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with http://www.example.com/1234/my-product-name vs http://www.example.com/my-product-name. You're over thinking it.